# "Warning: Missing argument 2 for WC_Custom_Product" in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am migrating a site to a new host and I am getting the following error. I do not quite understand what this error relates to and why it would be fine on the current host but showing this on new hosting despite it being an exact replication using the All-on-one Migration Plugin

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   WC_Custom_Product::action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary()
>   in /wp-content/themes/custom-theme/classes/wc-custom-product.php

The function looks like this, there is not a lot to it really but I don't know how to fix

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->product_id = get_the_ID();
    $this->product = wc_get_product( $this->product_id );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', array($this, 'action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary'), 10, 2 );
}

function action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary( 
    $woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash, $int ) { 
    echo "<div class='product-row first'>";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The Woocommerce action hook `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` located in [`content-product.php` template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php#L36-L42) **accepts only one argument** and it's mostly never used.

Note that action hooks doesn't need to return an argument as filter hooks does.

Also in your constructor function, you don't need to specify the number of arguments, and as no arguments are used in your hooked function, you can **just remove them all** just like woocommerce does [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L39) and [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L97).

So try this instead:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->product_id = get_the_ID();
    $this->product = wc_get_product( $this->product_id );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', array($this, 'action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary') );
}

public function action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary() { 
    echo "<div class='product-row first'>";
}
```

It should work without errors.

Comment: Confirming that this update has worked and I am no longer seeing the error message

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined the function it will only work with 2 parameters passed to it. The woocommerce action `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` apparently passes only one parameter, if at all.

So in order to circumvent this you just need to define default values to your parameters in such cases, so that the "missing argument" warning does not fire, like so:

```
function action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary(
$woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash = null, $int = 0 ) { 
    echo "<div class='product-row first'>";
}
```

Notice how for safe measure I defined `$woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash` as NULL? If the call to action passes any values to this function, the defaults (null and zero) will be overwritten.

Also, keep in mind that your "error" is in fact just a warning. It will not break your code and your function should work, but this depends on your PHP error settings, and you probably have warning messages visible or debug mode enabled in WordPress config.